# Tuples element comparison

Tags: python, tuples, compare

I have two tuples in a list where I want to compare their second element.
I know there are several ways for achieving this.

What is the idiomatic way in doing this?

Comment: Is the size of the list always going to be 2 and the element to be considered always going to be second or can they vary?

Comment: A more elegant way... I don't think so. Just keep it like that, it's simple and understandable.

Comment: Maybe if we saw the context, we could show something better. But with no context, I agree with @Shinra tensei.

Comment: Yes, I just had one more idea what seemed to be more elegant.

Answer (score 1):

OK, currently 5 possibilities:

```
import timeit
results = [(3, 2), (1, 2)]
print("#1", timeit.timeit(
    '''(_, a), (_, b) = results
a == b''',
    globals=globals(), number=10000000))
print("#2", timeit.timeit(
    '''(_, a), (_, b), *_ = results
a == b''',
    globals=globals(), number=10000000))
print("#3", timeit.timeit(
    '''results[0][1] == results[1][1]''',
    globals=globals(), number=10000000))
print("#4", timeit.timeit(
    '''len({r[1] for r in results}) == 1''',
    globals=globals(), number=10000000))
print("#5", timeit.timeit(
    "len(set(list(zip(*results))[1])) == 1",
    globals=globals(), number=10000000))
```

Unless I'm doing something wrong, the first method is the fastest in case of a list of 2 tuples, otherwise just use what you have

```
#1 0.6181712869999999
#2 1.597160365
#3 1.093676446
#4 3.0940490819999997
#5 4.806052006
```

Comment: Another: `len({r[1] for r in results}) == 1` (not good, but imho the better set solution).

Comment: Ok, 5 solutions, then.

Answer (score 1):

I think you code as written is the most "elegant" or easy to read as long as the reader of the code has a good idea what the content of the `results` is. If you want to provide him with more hints (for example if the content of `results` might be confusing etc.), you can name the variables within the result:

```
(_, height_a), (_, height_b) = results
height_a == height_b
```

Note that this only works if the `results` is pair of pairs, if there are multiple pairs within the results, you can work around that by:

```
(_, height_a), (_, height_b), *_ = results
```